# Debian/xfce kmix volume

Tags: linux, debian, xfce, kmix

Does anyone know how to make all the audio streams update at once? At the moment, if I update the main volume control it will not update everything. ie. there is a separate stream for Chrome, VLC, or any other program with volume. I need to update these on a per-program basis. Is there a way to control all programs at once?

Comment: You seem to be contradicting yourself: "I need to update these on a per-program basis. Is there a way to control all programs at once?". Do you want this per program or all at once?

Comment: @terdon perhaps I will rephrase. I want to update them all at once. I technically have to "update them on a per-program basis" right now (because I don't know any other way).

Comment: Well, each program has its own volume control but the global volume control should affect all of them. Are you saying that changing the global volume in kmix does not affect all programs? Does it do nothing then?

Comment: It changes them all but they are all uneven. Once program 1 gets to 100% volume, you can't get any higher, even though program 2 and 3 may be on 50%. So If i max out the volume of master, 1 program will have max volume and the rest will have a random selection of volumes that can't be raised.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do what you want. This is a feature not a bug. There are two ways of controlling your volume. The global volume control sets the output for the whole system. Now, if you also change the volume from within a particular program, that will affect the output of that program alone.

It is the same as connecting a portable CD player or an mp3 player to your HiFi. You can then change the volume from the main amplifier and you can also change it from the CD player. One sets the volume given by the device and the other the volume of the system as a whole.

Your OS works in a similar way, the individual program's volume sliders define how loud an output they send to the sound system (the amplifier in the analogy above), the global slider sets how loud an output the sound system should send to the speakers. The two are completely separate systems and cannot be combined (really not sure why you would want to).

Changing the global volume *does* affect all programs, it simply does not affect their own volume level. Think of the global volume control as a multiplier that is applied to all the individual volumes.

Comment: I'm not so sure I agree with this. If I set the program volume from within the program to the maximum, then raise my master volume to the top, I still need to go into kmix settings to raise the volume to the max for that program. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Peter huh? What do you mean? What do you raise in `kmix`? For that matter why are you using `kmix` at all, I assume you are on a Gnome desktop. How do you raise the volume for a single program in kmix, could you add some screenshots to your question to clarify?

Comment: I meant program as in a random program. ie. max out the volume in Google Chrome, max out the master volume, and the volume tab will still be at 50% until I go into kmix and change it manually. I am also using xfce, not gnome.

Comment: @Peter xfce OK, point is you're not using KDE which is why I wonder about `kmix`. Do you have separate sliders for each program in `kmix`? What volume tab? Seriously, please post a screenshot it is very hard to understand which volume you are referring to.